# How to find and index of ASCII charachter value 29 in the string java

Tags: java, ascii

I have a string from the scanner with Group separators ( GS ASDCII value 29) which are non printable characters in the string. How can I separate those groups? Looking for something like

```
indDelim = holdBarCode.indexOf((char)29);
```

so I can process the string.

Comment: Is there something you don't like about this "something like"?

Comment: String delim = String.valueOf((char) 29); returns -1, it doesn't see ASDCII non printable character . My question is how to find ASDCII non printable character in the string. 
And I don't want split, String may have more than one <GS> in it, and I will need to process it separate.

Comment: No, String.valueOf((char) 29) never returns -1. And if you store it in a String delim, and if your String actually does contain a character the ASCII code of which is decimal 29, then yourString.indexOf(delim) doesn't return -1 either. Please show the complete, entire program with absolutely all its data, that made you think so, so we can run it ourselves unmodified and see where you went wrong. Because it is not so.

Answer (score 1):

Most `String` splitting methods in Java are driven by a delimiter. The easiest way would be to use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) but you can also look into [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

```
String delim = String.valueOf((char) 29);
String[] groups = holdBarCode.split(delim);
```

Comment: String delim = String.valueOf((char) 29); returns -1, it doesn't see  ASDCII non printable character . My question is how to find ASDCII non printable character in the string

Comment: And I don't want split, String may have more than one <GS> in it, and I will need to process it separate.